# How can I take all pods of a Kubernetes deployment offline?

Tags: kubernetes

We have a Kubernetes cluster that has several deployments, each of which can have multiple pods running at a time (so far so standard). We need to do some database migrations (not hosted on the cluster), and can't have any of our code potentially altering values while that is happening - as such we need to take offline all pods of a few of the deployments for a short while, before spinning them back up again.

What we would like to do is find a reasonable way to have traffic that would be routed to those pods instead routed to just simple HTML error pages (where appropriate) while we're working, but without having to manually touch each pod as they can always be restarted or scaled while we're working.

Some relevant information that may help answer our query:

- We have a load balancer for the cluster as a whole which sits on top of our SSL terminator/reverse proxy (currently running on multiple pods as well).
- We have load balancers sitting in front of each deployment (i.e. the load balancer is responsible for routing subdomain traffic between the pods for a given deployment)
- We are hosted on Azure Kubernetes Service (if that makes a difference)
- The pods we want to take offline are running linux containers with Nginx

Answer (score 1):

> How can I take all pods of a Kubernetes deployment offline?

I would recommend to scale the Deployment to **0 replicas** in this case.

Use e.g.

```
kubectl scale deployment <my-app> --replicas=0
```

You can easyli restore this by scaling up to the number of replicas that you want.

You can also scale multiple deployments at the same time, if they have a common *label*:

```
kubectl scale deployment -l my-label=my-value --replicas=0
```

You can add labels to a Deployment with

```
kubectl label deployment <my-app> my-label=my-value
```